# iOS Crashlytics - Block crash reports from being send to server

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

I have installed the `Crashlytics` to my app, It's working fine and sends crash reports to the server.

But in my app `setting`, I'm having new option as `"Send crash reports" switch.`

So if the user toggle off the `switch` in setting page, It should `block` the `Crashlytics` report from being send to its server.

But i'm not seeing any option in the `Crashlytics` framework to block the reports or even stop the `Crashlytics` from running.

Is there any way to `block the reports or stop the Crashlytics` from running?

Comment: Don't think you can.  You'd have to avoid starting Crashlytics altogether, instead.

Comment: @trojanfoe. what if the scenario like crashlytics is already running and user tries to turned it off in settings?

Comment: You can adjust the exception handler so that Crashlytics never sees the crash.  See `NSGetUncaughtExceptionHandler` and `NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the setting changes, you can make sure Crashlytics is not enabled once the app restarts. In your app delegate, you can check for the setting and then enable Crashlytics.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Crashlytics
    //Check setting
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey: @"CanSendCrashReports"])
    {
        [Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
    } 
}
```