# Decide whether to send a Crashlytics (Apple) report based on flag

Tags: ios, crashlytics

I've added a switch to my privacy policy to allow people to opt out of sending Crashlytics reports and Answers analytics. I'm saving the preference in user preferences.

It's easy to not send to Answers; just wrap the call to the logging function in an if statement that checks user prefs. But I'm finding hard to disable Crashlytics reports once the app is already running.

I looked at their documentation, and they mention that you can make your app delegate the delegate for Crashlytics:

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().delegate = self
Fabric.with([Crashlytics.self])
```

And then use a delegate method to do things before sending the report:

```
func crashlyticsDidDetectReport(forLastExecution report: CLSReport, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void)
{
    // You should take some set of actions here based on knowing that a crash happened, but then make sure to call the completion handler
    // If you don't call the completion handler, the SDK will not submit the crash report.
    if reportsAllowed {
        completionHandler(true)
    }
}
```

I then forced a crash and the next time I run the app, the method is not called (I placed a breakpoint inside of it).

**Note:** I saw this answer ([iOS Crashlytics - Block crash reports from being send to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35719683/ios-crashlytics-block-crash-reports-from-being-send-to-server)), but that requires that people restart the app for the opt-in/out to take place.

Comment: AFAIK Crashlytics sends crash reports at the next startup, not when the crash is happening, so you should be fine with the delegate method. Also keep in mind that if the debugger is attached when the crash is happening then Crashlytics doesn't capture crashes, probably that's why the delegate is not called. Here is the reference for that: https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features

Comment: @DánielNagy thanks for the comment. I decided to make my life easier, and do the simple thing described in the answer I quoted. I just added a method to launch Crachlytics whenever the flag is changed to on.